# RSA implementation issue with converting text to BigInteger

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, biginteger

I was trying to create a simple RSA encryption/decryption program using Java. However, the encryption and decryption doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is when I try to turn a file into a bigInteger. Because after some debugging, I found out that the "decimal representation" of encryption and decryption matches up, it's just the translation from bigInteger to file that's causing problems.

This is how I read in the file:

```
File file = new File(inputPath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
int fileLen = (int)(file.length());
data = new byte[fileLen];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();
```

I tried to turn a file into the big integer (m) upon which I do the rest of the RSA stuff (c = m.modPow(e,n)).

```
BigInteger m = new BigInteger(data);
```

For decryption, I read the file and turn it into a bigInteger and use the m = c.modPow(d,n), and I use the following to build the cipher:

```
BigInteger c = new BigInteger(data);
```

And in both cases, I write the BigInteger the following way:

```
output = m.toByteArray(); or c.toByteArray();
fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
fos.write(output);
fos.close();
```

I know that the RSA modPow and key generation works, because if I print c and m as BigIntegers, they match up, but the files doesn't. Any idea why? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you think the problem is with your conversion, then isolate that part of the code and create an example that demonstrates your problem. Don't just give us all the code for your RSA class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `new BigInteger(1, data)`. You are generating negative numbers, RSA only uses positive numbers.